# Django create a register page which contains extra field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a register page which located www.mysite.com/register and contains "username,email,password" as usually and extra (gender,dateofbirth,workposition). Firstly i tried to make this by using this code but i failed. How can i create a Profile and RegisterPage which is using same User?

**in my accounts/forms.py**

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
username = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Kullanıcı Adı')
 password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
 password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label='Parola Doğrulama', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
 GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
)
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
class Meta:         model = User
       fields = [
        'username',
        'password1',
        'password2',
        'gender',

        ]
```

**in my accounts/views.py**

```
def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        user.set_password(password)
        # user.is_staff = user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, "accounts/form.html", {"form": form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'})
```

Comment: Do you have a Profile model ?

Comment: No sir. In fact i am newbie. I couldn't any article which explain clearly enough.

Comment: Django's default User model is not having the fields you are looking for. You have to look for overriding AbstractBaseUser https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: How about one to one way? Is it a possible way how can i implement with my fields?

Comment: OneToOne is the simplest way. By creating a Profile model and having a OneToOne Field will do the trick. Then you have to create another modelform for the Profile model, display the form in template, and in the views validate both forms, save the user form first and the profile for second.

Comment: Sir i created the profile model in user/models.py is it correct then i created user/forms.py and i created profileform and userform which takes information from AbstractBaseUser? Or i should add the code in accounts/models.py. I want to screen profile in www.site.com/user/profile and my register form will be in www.site.com/accounts/register. If you can give your mail i want to send my project to you